# Search field to search for WooCommerce products instead of blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I want to modify my Wordpress site theme feature, and modify the search tool from header to show just related products, instead showing me blog post. I searched a little, and found that just need to modify the query, so can use for searching woo products. This is my current search query:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo 
esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    printf( '<input type="search" 
class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" placeholder="%2$s" name="s" 
title="%3$s" />',
esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
get_search_query(),
esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
                    );
                ?>
<button type="submit" 
id="searchsubmit_header"></button>
</form>
```

i found that i should put this line:

```
<input type="hidden" class="" value="product" name="post_type" />
```

bellow

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

So it should looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo 
esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" class="" value="product" name="post_type" />
```

but still show me mixed results from Woo Products and Pages/Blog posts.

So my question is what to modify in query to search just for WooCommerce products instead of blog posts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Add a hidden field to search for products.

`<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">`

[Live example](https://badmarriages.net/search/) from one of my sites.

Example has separate forms to search posts, products, news.

Best wishes,
Mitchell